# Поиск в JSON строке значения

Tags: c#

Мне нужно получить значение из динамичного JSON.
Он огромен , поэтому приводить его полностью не имеет смысла. Меня интересует значения тиража, как мне туда добраться максимально изящно?

По логике мне надо найти слово Тираж в строке и перейти в соседнюю ячейку и получить значение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: десериализуешь строку в объект и обращаешься к конкретному полю

Comment: Я не хочу создавать классы для этой цели. Нельзя просто найти слово тираж и перейти в соседнюю ячейку?

Comment: И поле конкретным не может быть. В другом файле позиция тиража может быть под-другой цифрой

Comment: _Нельзя просто найти слово тираж и перейти в соседнюю ячейку_ - ты уверен, что у тебя во всем объекте будет только одно слово "Тираж"?

Comment: _И поле конкретным не может быть. В другом файле позиция тиража может быть под-другой цифрой_ Искать в массиве объектов с помощью того же linq намного проще чем делать поиск в строке

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь готовыми парсерами. Читать JSON поиском или регулярными выражениями - не очень хорошая идея. Например, свойство `Value` не обязано идти до свойства `Name`, оно может идти и после него. Смысл JSON при этом не изменится, а отловить все такие случаи при поиске будет тяжело.

[Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) поддерживает такую вещь, как запросы [JSONPath](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm):

```
var json = @"{
    ""Editions"": {},
    ""ItemType"": 5,
    ""Capabilities"": {
        ""Capabilities"": [
            {
                ""Name"": ""Тираж"",
                ""Value"": ""20000"",
                ""AdditionalProperties"": {}
            },
            {
                ""Name"": ""aaaa"",
                ""Value"": ""bbb"",
                ""AdditionalProperties"": {}
            }
        ]
    }
}";

var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
var value = (string)obj.SelectToken("$.Capabilities.Capabilities[?(@.Name == 'Тираж')].Value");
```

Если JSON действительно огромный и десериализовать целиком его накладно по памяти, то придется воспользоваться [JsonTextReader](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadJsonWithJsonTextReader.htm), десереализуя только небольшие части файла (код приблизительный, без проверок):

```
string value = null;
using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json))) {
    // читаем json, пока не придем в объект Capabilities
    while (reader.Read()) {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName &&
            (string)reader.Value == "Capabilities")
        {           
            break;
        }
    }

    reader.Read();

    // каждый объект из массива десериализуем в JObject
    while (reader.Read()) {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject) {
            var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
            if ((string)obj["Name"] == "Тираж") {
                value = (string)obj["Value"];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Опередили меня :)

Comment: Исправьте на var value = (string)json_obj.SelectToken("$.Capabilities.Capabilities[?(@.Name == 'Тираж')].Value"); и я помечу как ответ! У Вас получилось это красивее!

Comment: @shatoidil поправил

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему следующим образом.

```
JObject json_obj = JObject.Parse(json_data);
JArray capabilities = (JArray)json_obj["Capabilities"]["Capabilities"];
var сirculation = capabilities.Where(c => (string)c["Name"] == "Тираж").Select(c => c["Value"]).FirstOrDefault();
```